# Resize of a banner as a carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, autoresize

Hi everyone so im having some troubles with my banner in bootstrap, I cant re-size my banner while its a carousel, meaning if the window gets smaller and bigger etc litterly went to the earth and back cant find a code that can help.  here is the code

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="header.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1></h1>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

any help

Comment: How are you trying to resize the banner?

Comment: im just trying to make it fit on to the website when ever i move it to make it bigger or smaller, this is my first website sorry im a amateur.

Comment: We are going to need to see more of your code. Can you attach the relevant CSS, or use JSFiddle to better demonstrate your issue?

Comment: "_litterly went to the earth and back_" To the Earth AND BACK? Back to where?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what you’re trying to do, but to resize an element based on percentage, you can use some basic CSS:

```css
#banner {
 position:absolute;
    background-image: url("media/americ11.jpg");
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

When I resize the window to make it taller or smaller, the banner will get taller or smaller. The width won’t, though, because it’s at 100%. Hope this helps!